# Java -- Pass variable from class to class

Tags: java

I know that to pass from within the **Same** class, I would do something like this --- but what about between classes?

```
class TestMe{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int numberAlpha = 232;
        TestMe sendNumber = new TestMe();
        sendNumber.Multiply(numberAlpha);
    }

    void Multiply(int var)
    {
        var+=40;
    }
}
```

Comment: create an instance and pass the variable using the appropriate instance method. please read [Classes and Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/).

Comment: Look up the JavaDocs and objects/methods

Comment: That's... an odd way to "pass a variable in the same class".  Can `Multiply` not be made static?  As for your question in general, it might be easier if you distinguish between "class" and "object."  You're not passing a variable "to the same class."  You're create an object of type `TestMe` and calling a function on it.  You can create an object of any other type you'd like and call a function on that exactly the same way.

Comment: You definitely need to look for a nice reading about general and then object oriented programming.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is it about passing by reference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use getters and setters.

```
class A {
    private int a_number;
    public int getNumber() { return a_number; }
}
class B {
    private int b_number;
    public void setNumber(int num) { b_number = num; }
}
```

.. And in your main method, wherever it is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    int blah = a.getNumber();
    B b = new B();
    b.setNumber(blah);
}
```

You can also use constructors as a means of an "initial setter" so that the object is always created with a minimum set of variables already instantiated, for example:

```
class A {
    private int a_number;
    public A(int number) { // this is the only constructor, you must use it, and you must give it an int when you do
        a_number = number;
    }
    public int getNumber() { return a_number; }
}
```